# How do I pass a date value to a cursor in plsql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

Basically I would like to pass a date value to a cursor, and print out the entire row/record after for each found.  I am having trouble because a) I don't know if my date is being converted properly in the BEGIN section, and b) I am getting "wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'" when printing each row.

This is what I have so far:

```
DEFINE B_HIREDATE = 11-OCT-88

DECLARE
  cursor DATE_CUR (the_date DATE) is
    select * from employees
      where hire_date > to_date(the_date, 'dd-mon-yy')
      order by hire_date;

  r_emp DATE_CUR%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  for r_emp IN DATE_CUR('&B_HIREDATE') LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line(r_emp);
  end LOOP;
END;
/
```

I am getting no output values, even if I change my select statement to a known single field name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't print out the whole row from a single `DBMS_OUTPUT` call, unfortunately; you'll need to print each column returned by the cursor individually. `PUT_LINE` [expects a `VARCHAR2` argument](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i1000105) or something that can be implicitly converted. You can concatenate several values into one call. Nice formatting isn't easy though.

The date conversion is almost OK, but you should have the `TO_DATE` in the cursor call, as the cursor parameter is expecting a `DATE`; and you should use `RR` instead of `YY` in your date mask, or preferably use 4-digit years and mask `YYYY`.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DEFINE B_HIREDATE = 11-OCT-1988

DECLARE
  cursor DATE_CUR (the_date DATE) is
    select * from employees
      where hire_date > the_date
      order by hire_date;    
BEGIN
  for r_emp IN DATE_CUR(TO_DATE('&B_HIREDATE','DD-MON-YYYY')) LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line(r_emp.hire_date);
  end LOOP;
END;
```

You don't need to explicitly declare the `r_emp` as a variable with this cursor syntax (but you would with the `OPEN`/`FETCH`/`CLOSE` version).

If you're running this in SQL*Plus, you need to add `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` at the start to allow the `DBMS_OUTPUT` calls to be displayed. You can do that in SQL Developer too, or there's a separate pane for viewing the output, which you need to enable for the worksheet.