# PL SQL - for loop through cursor

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, cursor

I'm having issues looping through my cursor

I have multiple location_name entries that i'm trying to display 5 at a time, and set it to look_item_cursor.

```
CURSOR look_item_cursor IS

  SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT location_name
            FROM inventory_info_v i
           WHERE i.item_code = lr_item.item_code) a
   WHERE rownum <= (ln_page + 4)
     AND rownum >= ln_page;
```

the original query returns the data back just fine.
both ln_page and lr_item.item_code are filled by the time the cursor is called.

I attempt to retrieve each of the 5 returned location_name, one at a time, with

```
OPEN look_item_cursor;
      BEGIN
        FOR lv_location_name IN look_item_cursor LOOP
          pv_message_return := pv_message_return ||
                               lv_location_name.location_name;
        END LOOP;
      END;
CLOSE look_item_cursor;
```

with lv_location_name being assigned as a

```
look_item_cursor%ROWTYPE
```

However I'm getting a general exception when it  runs through the query, and i'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: **please** post a complete stack trace.

Comment: If you use cursor `FOR` loop (as you are trying to do in your example) then 1. do not open a cursor explicitly (cursor `FOR` loop does it for you); 2. do not declare cursor loop variable explicitly as you said you did with `lv_location_name` variable  (cursor `FOR` loop does it for you). So you either work with a cursor explicitly  (Open, fetch and close explicitly), or you use cursor `FOR` loop, which does most of the work for you (opens the cursor, declares cursor variable, fetches and closes the cursor).

Comment: very helpful, thank you. Do i need to include an 'exit when' at all for this type of loop? i ask because it errors upon assigning the 5th and final entry EDIT: nevermind that was something stupid. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

From [oradoc](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155)

> **Cursor FOR LOOP Statement**
>   The cursor FOR LOOP statement implicitly declares its loop index as a record variable of the row type that a specified cursor returns, and then opens a cursor. With each iteration, the cursor FOR LOOP statement fetches a row from the result set into the record. When there are no more rows to fetch, the cursor FOR LOOP statement closes the cursor. The cursor also closes if a statement inside the loop transfers control outside the loop or raises an exception.

Try something like this (replace the test data with your query inside `in (...) loop)`:

```
begin
    for row_ in (
        select 1 id, 'item 1' name from dual union all      
        select 2 id, 'item 2' name from dual union all      
        select 3 id, 'item 3' name from dual 
        ) loop
        dbms_output.put_line('id:'||row_.id||' name:'||row_.name);
    end loop;
end; 

-- dbms output
id:1 name:item 1
id:2 name:item 2
id:3 name:item 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is making the cursor to get opened twice:

- explicitly in `OPEN look_item_cursor`
- implicitly in initialization of `FOR-LOOP`

I suppose you get [ORA-06511: PL/SQL Cursor already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697843/ora-06511-pl-sql-cursor-already-open) exception.
To avoid it - remove OPEN and CLOSE statements, just use cursor in loop and it will be opened and closed automatically.

---

It is necessary to be wary of some problem-makers I notice in the code:

1. Declaring loop variable is not necessary. Remove it from declaration section - just use it locally in `FOR-LOOP`.
2. Passing variable `ln_page` from outer contex should be fixed by strict [cursor parameter passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773494/how-do-i-pass-a-date-value-to-a-cursor-in-plsql).
3. Lower border for rownum (`AND rownum >= ln_page`) won't work as you expect. On Oracle 12c use `LIMIT ROWS` clause, otherwise inline view with row numbers is required. Both cases are particularly described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering).

Comment: this was solved per @Nicholas Krasnov s comment. very helpful, thank you